# invalid argument Storageservice.prototype.setItem

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

When i trying to set data in localstorage using setItem and get the data using getItem, everything works fine in chrome and firefox but not working in IE or Edge.

In Edge getting these errors.

> uncaught (in promise): Error : invalid argument
>
> invalid argument Storageservice.prototype.setItem
>
> unhandled promise rejection : invalid argument., zone:angular  ;
>   task:promise.then ; value: Error : invalid argument.error : invalid
>   argument.

In IE :

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): QuotaExceededError ORIGINAL
>   STACKTRACE: Error: Uncaught (in promise): QuotaExceededError
>   Unhandled Promise rejection: QuotaExceededError ; Zone: angular ;
>   Task: Promise.then ; Value: QuotaExceededError undefined

i am using following code snippet-

```
setItem(key: string, data: any, storageType: string = 'localStorage'): any {
    let _storage: any = localStorage;
    if (storageType !== 'localStorage') {
      //sessionStorage maybe?
      _storage = sessionStorage;
    }

    let _data = this.transform('set', (typeof data === "string") ? data : JSON.stringify(data));
    _storage.setItem(key, _data);
  }


  /**
   * getItem(key) returns the cache object from storage
   */
  getItem(key: string, ifNotFound: any = {}, storageType: string = 'localStorage'): any {
    let _storage: any = localStorage;
    if (storageType !== 'localStorage') {
      //sessionStorage maybe?
      _storage = sessionStorage;
    }
    let _data = _storage.getItem(key);
    if (_data) {
      try {
        return JSON.parse(this.transform('get', _data));
      } catch (e) {
        return ifNotFound;
      }
    }
    return ifNotFound;
  }

  /**
   * transform() returns the object transformed to storage
   */
   transform(type: string = 'set', data: any): any {
     var isMSIE = (/trident/i).test(navigator.userAgent);
     if (isMSIE) {
       return data;
     } else {
       if (type === 'set') {
         //compress the data to Base64 and then do unicode encoding
          return LZString.compress(data);
         /*return this.encodeModal.encoder.compress(data);*/
       } else {
         //transform for fetch

         return LZString.decompress(data);
         //return this.encodeModal.encoder.decompress(data);
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: How about code that you tried so far ?

Comment: @BelminBedak I have updated my questions please see.

Comment: Quota Exceeded error In IE11 we need to used LZString to compress the data and set in session storage.